# How to install Debian GNU/Linux on HP Chromebook 14? USB boot doesn't works!

Tags: debian, debian-installer, chrome-book

Following [this guide from the debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/HP/Chromebook%2014), I'm tring to install Debian on my HP Chromebook 14 (FALCO).

The problem is that, when I choose "Install" in the Debian-Installer's menu, instead of the installation process I receive again the screen stating that the OS verification has been turned off (Developer mode).

I want to install Debian Jessie on a SD, booting the Debian-Installer from a USB stick.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem.[over here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/224998/115315). The 32bit debian version worked, as well as trisqel and archbang. Still trying to get 64bit debian to run or at least find out a bit more about the problem....

Comment: Both of you guys are getting further than me on a Toshiba Satellite Chromebook [over here](http://superuser.com/q/1035433). I can't even get the firmware to stop telling me the USB thumbdrive is not Chrome OS.

Comment: In the case of Acer chromebooks that get into the situation you describe, the [Chromium OS docs](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/acer-c720-chromebook) state to ***`chromeos-firmwareupdate --sb_extract /tmp; flashrom -w /tmp/bios.bin -i RW_LEGACY`***.